# How to save model in .pb format and then load it for inference in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am newbie of Tensorflow and trying to run one tutorial code located in https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/02_Convolutional_Neural_Network.ipynb

Based on this code, I would like to try to save the model in .pb format using `simple_save` and restore it for testing but I have no idea how to modify this piece of code. I have browsed some web pages but still didn't get the idea. Can anyone help me change this piece of code so that I can save the trained model and then load it for inference? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving model, you need two things - input and output tensor names. In your case, input tensor is called `x` and output tensor is `y_pred` and `y_pred_cls` (mentioned in `In [29]` in [notebook](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/02_Convolutional_Neural_Network.ipynb)). Here's simple example to save your model:

```
simple_save(session,
            export_dir,
            inputs={"x": x,},
            outputs={"y_pred": y_pred,
                     "y_pred_cls": y_pred_class})
```

EDIT:
Restoring-

```
restoring_graph = tf.Graph()
with restoring_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=restoring_graph) as sess:
       # Restore saved values
       tf.saved_model.loader.load(
          sess,
          [tag_constants.TRAINING],
          export_dir  # Path to SavedModel
       )
      # Pass inputs to model and do predictions below
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also help with loading the model for testing? I guess that I should add something in block 42 but no idea how the code exactly look like...

Comment: @KathyLee Added loading example, Check for updated answer

Comment: Sorry, but what is tag_constants.TRAINING?